# Make it for a database (tr, commas, spaces, csv)

Tags: linux, csv, tr

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
NAME SURNAME EMAIL
Joe  Doe     jd@domain.com
Jane Doe     jane@domain.com
```

And I want it to look like this

```
NAME,SURNAME,EMAIL
Joe,Doe,jd@domain.com
Jane,Doe,jane@domain.com
```

So basically I want to add commas after each word (apart from the last one in the row) and remove spaces so I can save it as csv and import it to postgresql.

I've searched online a lot and there are similar questions there, but nothing seems to work the way I want it. I don't have much experience with this, but I know I would like tu use tr command only (not sed) if possible.

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: What have you tried?  This is an easy one-liner, but I want to see what you did that didn't work.

Comment: I have closed those tabs now (private window), but if I remember correctly (among the others) it was something like: cat myfile| tr '\\n'  ',' > newfile. Things like that. It messed it up. I thought it was the "n" part, because it sounded to me like a "new line". But after I removed this "n" switch tr was returning error. I got confused at some point because I barely used tr in my life. I'm starting to like it,

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do anything with new lines.  You need to replace all occurrences of repeated spaces with a comma.  That's `tr -s  " "  "," < infile > outfile`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Just one more thing. In your solution everything works and there is no comma after the last word in the row, but there is one in front of the first one in the row (like ,NAME or ,Joe for example). Is there a simple way to get rid of it?

Comment: That would mean you have a space at the beginning of each line.  `tr` can't handle both things in one shot.  You can say `cut -c 2- < infile | tr -s " " "," > outfile`.